# Impossible to have plotband through current date in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highstock/highcharts, and plotting a stacked (and grouped) column, based on the last 5 minutes.

I want to highlight the last minute (and have been using a plotband for that).

My problem is that the plotband will not cover the whole time range, as you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/duuuE/1/

What I want the plotband to cover is the last minute (up until the current timestamp), but using stacked/grouped columns makes it weird, because the columns are not drawn at the corresponding x-axis tick that corresponds to the timestamp.

Code is this:

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
var now = new Date().getTime();
var last10min = now - (10 * 60 * 1000);
var lastMin = now - (60 * 1000);
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        minTickInterval: 60 * 1000,
        tickMarkPlacement: 'on',
        plotBands: [{ // highlight last minute
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: lastMin,
            to: now
        }],
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: last10min,
            pointInterval: 60 * 1000 // one minute
        },
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            pointPlacement: 'between'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5]
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove `pointPlacement` from your options, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/duuuE/2/

Reported issue to [bug tracker](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2188).

Possible workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/duuuE/7/

Comment: Well... removing pointPlacement actually helps highlighting as far as the end of the x-axis, but in this case (using columns), the column is  off the proper time frame...as its placement doesn't correspond to the x-axis value.

Comment: I think it really does - when you take actual time, it has also seconds and milliseconds. Set it to 0 and you will have proper placement for columns, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/duuuE/3/

Comment: Actually... that doesn't solve the problem: there are 10 values to display (1 for each minute range), there are 10 tickets displayed (1 for each minute for the last 10 min), and I want to highlight the last minute): you'll see in the fiddle you list that the plotband and the last column value don't overlap properly... though they correspond to the same time range.

Comment: You are right, this is but, I have reported this [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2188). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on that. Just wondering: do you know any other way I could "highlight" the last column(s) that correspond to the last interval in my chart ?

Comment: Another option will be to use renderer to draw rect in that place. Or you cna add another series, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/duuuE/7/

Comment: Except it requires to use the grouping: false option so that the series can overlap, but I'm already using a grouped (and have to...) stacked column type :(

Comment: So I advice to wait for bugfix, or implement something with renderer. Just to confirm you are using grouped, not stacked (like in first example) columns, right?

Comment: I'm using stacked AND grouped columns yes.

Comment: I finally achieved what I wanted by setting a specific color to the last entry, and switching it with a setInterval to the same color with 0.5 opacity.

Comment: Could you share with jsFiddle example?

Comment: This is the code I came up with, doing what I wanted (highlight the last value for each series in a column chart): http://jsfiddle.net/k9mR8/1/